# Coulomb Gauge under Lorentz Boost

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, gauge-invariance, lorentz-symmetry, gauge

In the Coulomb gauge for the Maxwell potential we have 
$$
A^0 = 0 \\
\partial_i A^i = 0
$$

Under an infinitesimal Lorentz Transformation with parameter $\epsilon$, we have

$$
A^\mu(x) \rightarrow A'^\mu(x) = A^\mu(x) + \epsilon^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu}A^\nu(x)$$

But then the Coulomb gauge no longer holds as
$$
A'^0 = 0 + \epsilon^{0}_{\ \ \nu}A^\nu(x) \neq 0$$

So we add a supplementary gauge term $\lambda(x,\epsilon)$

$$
A^\mu(x) \rightarrow A'^\mu(x) = A^\mu(x) + \epsilon^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu}A^\nu(x) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\lambda(x,\epsilon)$$

If I perform this Lorentz Transformation now, can I say Coulomb gauge now holds due to the $\lambda$? So we have
$$
A'^0 = 0 \\
\partial_i A'^i = 0
$$
Is this the entire point of the supplementary gauge term?

Comment: God yes - exams are getting to me. Edit made.

Comment: That is correct.